# Move Directory in perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to move a directory using perl within the same  volume in ubuntu.

I used the move ( File::Copy ) command in Perl like below

```
move($dir1, $dir2);.  # Doesn't work.
```

Expecation is that $dir1 will be place under $dir2 after the move. But got an error saying that 'Is a directory'.

But when I use system mv it works perfectly.

```
system("mv $dir1 $dir2"); #This works!.
```

I searched google and understood that move should works exactly like mv in linux?.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

If you want to move the directory `./dir1` under `./dir2` call move like this:

```
move("./dir1", "./dir2/dir1");
```

I think you are doing:

```
move("./dir1", "./dir2/");
```

which complains because `./dir2` already exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try this. I was under the impression that behaviour of system mv and perl move are exactly same. Looks like there are some usage differences!.

Comment: All seven of those `./` are useless!

Comment: Without them the stuff looks weird to me but thanks. I'm glad there's only 7 :)

Answer (score 0):

```
use File::Copy::Recursive;
rmove('foo/bar/baz', '/etc/');
```

Comment: This I have tried.  Looks rmove is doing a copy then delete the original. Way too slow and does't serve my purpose.